# Pass model assigned value to component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

```
import { IJobScheduleFrequency } from "../interfaces/job-schedule-frequency.interface";

export class JobSchedule {
  constructor(
    public dagName: string = "My First dag",
    public folderName?: string,
    public dataLineID?: string,
    
  ) { }
}
```

I need to pass this `dagName` into *jobscheduler.component.ts* file. How can I get the `dagName` in component.